# How to run golang script in PM2?

Tags: ubuntu, startup, pm2, auto

How do you auto start golang scripts in PM2 on Ubuntu 20.04? this is how I run golang scripts:

```
./rimgo
```

I tried `pm2 start "./rimgo" --name rimgo` but it didn't work. What is the correct command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow this steps :

1. Create you binary using  `go build main.go`
2. give execution permission to the binary using `sudo chmod +x main`.
3. create a `package.json` file:

```json
{
    "apps" : [{
      "name"        : "main",
      "script"      : "./main"
    }]
}
```

and finally:

execute :

```sh
pm2 start package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I already run a Golang script. Check this steps:

1. `go build main.go` For to build the script. This must generate a `main` binary file.
2. Grant execution permission for this file with `sudo chmod +x main`
3. Try to execute from command line with `./main`
4. Update the pm2 to latest & type `pm2 start ./main --name FooBar`

Answer (score 0):

the first time, inside from folder app golang
create build binary app

$ go build main.go

before write in the terminal

$ pm2 start ./appGo/main